# Are the Torah's 5 Book divisions (Bereshit, etc.) justified by the Hebrew text?

Tags: minhag, history, torah-study

I wonder if the Hebrew text divides the scroll of Moses as clearly into 5 Books/Sections as modern translations do (by adding titles as if they are 5 books of Moses), or whether, for example, the Hebrew text transitions from Bereshit to Shemot, from Shemot to Vayyiqra, from Vayyiqra to Bemidbar, and from Bemidbar to Devarim without any special indication as to whether they should be treated as separate chapters.

Comment: Do you have any sources why you would think differently?

Comment: In Torah scrolls there are 4 blank lines left in between each book. Is that the sort of answer you seek?

Comment: @DoubleAA yes that is the sort of answer I seek, but only if the 4 blank lines are only present between each book and not present anywhere else inside the books themselves.